Python WinAPI SetWindowsHookExA fails
I am trying to disable only keyboard input on Windows. Therefore, I want to register a hook, which will not call the next hook.
from ctypes import *

def hookProc(nCode, wParam, lParam):
    return 0

CMPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_int, POINTER(c_void_p))
res = windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExA(13, CMPFUNC(hookProc), windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(None), 0)
print(res)

This prints 0 on my Windows 11 machine. Why?

Include error handling to get the error message from GetLastError() to understand why SetWindowsHookExA fails.

@IlyaKhrustalev 126 - ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND

Listing [Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python.
Most likely, the error is due to [SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer) (a common pitfall when working with CTypes (calling functions)).
code00.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys
from ctypes import wintypes as wts


WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13

HOOKProc = cts.WINFUNCTYPE(cts.c_size_t, cts.c_int, wts.WPARAM, wts.LPARAM)
LowLevelKeyboardProc = HOOKProc


SetWindowsHookExA = cts.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExA
SetWindowsHookExA.argtypes = (cts.c_int, HOOKProc, wts.HINSTANCE, wts.DWORD)
SetWindowsHookExA.restype = wts.HHOOK

UnhookWindowsHookEx = cts.windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx
UnhookWindowsHookEx.argtypes = (wts.HHOOK,)
UnhookWindowsHookEx.restype = wts.BOOL

GetModuleHandleW = cts.windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW
GetModuleHandleW.argtypes = (wts.LPCWSTR,)
GetModuleHandleW.restype = wts.HMODULE

GetLastError = cts.windll.kernel32.GetLastError
GetLastError.argtypes = ()
GetLastError.restype = wts.DWORD


def llKbHook(nCode, wParam, lParam):
    print(nCode, wParam, lParam)
    return 0


def main(*argv):
    hook = SetWindowsHookExA(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc(llKbHook), GetModuleHandleW(None), 0)
    if not hook:
        print(f"SetWindowsHookExA failed: {GetLastError()}")
    else:
        print(f"Hook: {hook}")
        input("Press <Enter> to exit... ")
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
            " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
            64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
            sys.platform,
        )
    )
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)

Output:

[cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q078638489]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
Python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32

Hook: 215421357
Press <Enter> to exit...

Done.


Might also want to read:

[SO]: How do I hook a ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW by using ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW? (@CristiFati's answer)

[SO]: SetWindowsHookExW returns 0 with no error | HID Mouse hook attempt (@CristiFati's answer)


